# Conv nets accuracy not changing while loss decreases

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm training several CNNs to do image classification in TensorFlow. The training losses decrease normally. However the test accuracy never changed throughout the whole training procedure, plus the accuracy is very low (0.014) where the accuracy for randomly guessing would be 0.003 (There are around 300 classes). One thing I've noticed is that only those models that I applied batch norm to showed such a weird behavior. What can possibly be wrong to cause this issue? The training set has 80000 samples, in case you might figure this was caused by overfitting. Below is part of the code for evaluation:

Accuracy function:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Model(test_image), 1), tf.argmax(test_image_label, 0))
accuracy = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)
```

the `test_image` is a batch with only one sample in it while the `test_image_label` is a scalar.

Session:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord, start=True)
    print('variables initialized')

    step = 0
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        sess.run(enqueue_train)
        print('epoch: %d' %epoch)
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            save_path = saver.save(sess, savedir + "/Model")
        for batch in range(num_batch):
            if step % 400 == 0:
                summary_str = cost_summary.eval(feed_dict={phase: True})
                file_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
            else:
                sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={phase: True})
            step += 1
    sess.run(train_close)


    sess.run(enqueue_test)
    accuracy_vector = []
    for num in range(len(testnames)):
        accuracy_vector.append(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={phase: False}))
    mean_accuracy = sess.run(tf.divide(tf.add_n(accuracy_vector), len(testnames)))
    print("test accuracy %g"%mean_accuracy)
    sess.run(test_close)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, savedir + "/Model_final")

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

    file_writer.close()
```

The `phase` above is to indicate if it is training or testing for the batch norm layer. 
Note that I tried to calculate the accuracy with the training set, which led to the minimal loss. However it gives the same poor accuracy. Please help me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Which loss function are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I solved this problem by fixing the batch normalization, which messed up the testing phase.